# When I have an anchor tag refrencing another section in the same page, how do I make it not to display immediately i have clicked it

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
  <html>
    <body>
      <UL>
                        <li>
                            <a class="boss" >Home</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a  id = "#About">About</a>
                        </li>
                    
                        <li>
                            <a id="#Services">Services</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a id="#Contact">Contact</a>
                        </li>
     </UL>
    
     <section id="About">
                <div class ="About">
                    <h2>About</h2>
                <image>
                <image>
                <image>
                <image>
 </section>
```

this is my code, when clicked any link above, it links to a page down, but the speed at which it references the section is too quick and I want to reduce it

oh solved just set scroll behaviour to be smooth

Comment: Are all of these question tags relevant?

Comment: _"this is my code"_ - This is a mess of invalid markup with [deprecated elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/image) that shouldn't be used anymore.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `scroll-behavior` and set it to `smooth` in CSS:

```css
html {
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
```

This will have a smooth transition when you click a button with an ID tag of the element.